# Passing and Receiving data from Python Script

Tags: python, node.js, express, command-line-arguments

I wanted to run a python script from my node-express app (when an endpoint is hit).
I wanted to pass the body of the request to the python script as command line argument (or if there is any other way).

I also want the data that the script returns to be returned as the response.

Can anyone help me with a way to achieve this efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi 
You can use the "child_process" package in your nodejs code and run your python script and have communication with it
That is your python code

```py
# hello.py

import random, time
while True:
    time.sleep(random.random() * 5)  # wait 0 to 5 seconds
    text = "Hello number " + (random.random() * 100)
    print(text, flush=True, end='')
```

And this will be your js code

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const messages = []; // Store readings

const sensor = spawn('python', ['hello.py']);
sensor.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    messages.push(parseFloat(data));

    // Log to debug
    console.log(messages);
});
```

If you want to pass the param to your python source code do this

```js
const myList = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const python = spawn('python',["script.py", JSON.stringify(myList)]);
```

And that will be your python code

```py
# script.py

import sys, json
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_list = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Yeah, I got what you said but my main query was how to pass arguments (mainly JavaScript Objects) to that python code through node.

Comment: Yup. Got it. Thanks mate.